# how to insert value into column of existing table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

How to insert value into column of existing table?

I have a table which have 5 column

```
id | firstname | lastname | address | email                | course_id 
1  | Waleed    | Khan     | Karachi | something@gmail.com  |   null
```

This table has 1000 rows but I added `course_id` column and want to insert value from another table named `Courses`.

Comment: -is there any relation between courses table and your created table, if then please mention the column name other than course_id

Comment: You have to explain the relationship between the courses table and the students table. How do you know which student takes which course?

Comment: You need an `UPDATE`, probably like this `UPDATE tab SET course_id = (SELECT course_id FROM other_table WHERE other_table.student_id = tab.id)`. Btw, this is probably bad idea, a student might have more than one course.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to specify what relationship the two tables are sharing. As mentioned in your question you want to create a `column_id` column in `Students` table. You'll create this column and then add foreign key constraint to the column. Add the constraint using `ALTER TABLE Students ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (column_id) REFERENCES Courses(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

`CASCADE` on deleteion and updation will take care of record updation and deletion in `Students` table.

Comment: You really want to delete a student when a course is deleted?

Comment: no i just want to insert value into student table course_id column from courses table course id column